# Select function takes more time during bootup

Tags: select, networking, embedded-linux

We have simple client/server application.
We run server on the beaglebone black based custom board.

We are starting a server in the init script, client running on the host PC is trying to connect continuously to server.
select function call is used in the server application to check for events on server socket before a accept is called, as follows
`selectOperationStatus = select(socketfd + 1, &readfds, (fd_set *)NULL, (fd_set *)NULL, &tv);`

`if (selectOperationStatus > 0){`
`clientFd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &sin_size)`
`}`

We observed that during boot, select function call takes 13 seconds to accept connection from client.
But if the same server application is started sometime after booting it connects withing 1 second.

Why select function takes time(~13 seconds) at bootup ?
Any suggestions/pointers for debugging? Any alternative of this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after some debugging we found that actual problem is it takes time for dhcp client of the board to get an ip. As soon as ip is assigned select() function returns.
So select function was not the actual culprit which we initially thought of. Though program was stuck at select function, actual problem was after bootup dhcp took time to assign the ip; at times dhcp took 7-12 seconds to assign the ip.

DHCP server was running in the ubuntu installed in the virtualbox, when we connected board to router ip was assignment became fast(within 3-5 seconds).